# Error - Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm getting an error message saying 'Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\SUL-I\fatest2.py", line 42, in  leftsensor = fa.ReadLine(0) File "C:\Users\SUL-I\FA.py", line 180, in ReadLine self._flush(self) TypeError: _flush() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given' when I run a bit of Python code I've written.

Here is the code:

```
#brings in external references
import FA 
import time

#defines some constants
black = 0
white = 200
correction = 10
w = 0

#controls the first robot, remember to update the com port number
fa = FA.Create()
comport = 7
fa.ComOpen(comport)
time.sleep(5) 
fa.PlayNote(294,800)
fa.PlayNote(330,800)
fa.PlayNote(262,800)
fa.LEDWrite(24)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(60)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(36)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(102)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(66)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(195)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(129)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(195)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(66)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(102)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(36)
time.sleep(0.25)
fa.LEDWrite(60)
leftsensor = fa.ReadLine(0)
rightsensor = fa.ReadLine(1)

while w < 100:
    if leftsensor >= white:
                fa.SetMotors(20,10)
    elif rightsensor >= white:
                fa.SetMotors(10,20)
    else:
                fa.Forwards(10)
    w = w+1

ComClose(comport)
```

Here is ReadLine in the FA module:

```
    def ReadLine(self, index):
        """Read the line sensor value

        Args:
            index: Line sensor to query (0 to 1)

        Returns:
            int: Value of Line sensor (0 to 4095)
        """
        self._flush(self)
        s = 'ReadLine {0}\n'.format(int(index))
        self.__ser.write(s.encode())
        r = self._readval("ReadLine", 1, 1)
        return(r);
```

definition of readval:

```
def _readval(self, cmd, loop_max):
        r = -1
        loop = 0
        while (loop < loop_max):
            try:
                r = int(self.__ser.readline().rstrip())
                if (self.__verbose != 0):
                    msg = '{0}: {1}'.format(cmd, r)
                    print(msg)
                loop = loop_max + 1   #break out of loop
            except ValueError:
                if (self.__verbose != 0):
                    msg = '{0}: No return({1})'.format(cmd,loop)
                    print(msg)
            loop = loop + 1
        return(r);
```

Comment: `self` is implicitly passed to methods, replace `self._flush(self)` with `self._flush()`

Comment: Ok I followed this advice, and now I have another similar error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SUL-I\fafollowline4.py", line 42, in <module>
    leftsensor = fa.ReadLine(0)
  File "C:\Users\SUL-I\FA.py", line 183, in ReadLine
    r = self._readval("ReadLine", 1, 1)
TypeError: _readval() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Please show the definition of `_readval`, the error comes from there but you don't have it in your code. (PS: for the future, please add additional error messages and information diectly in your question, as you see comments lose formatting and tracebacks become unreadable)

Comment: Readval definition is now in the question

Comment: `_readval` is only expecting the `"Readline"` and the first `1` argument; it doesn't know what to do with the second `1` argument.

Comment: Thanks chepner and Gphilo. The robot is now working exactly as it should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having resolved the error involving `_flush_`, your second error occurs for similar reasons.

Compare the definition of `_readval`:

```
def _readval(self, cmd, loop_max):
```

to your call:

```
r = self._readval("ReadLine", 1, 1)
```

`"Readline"` is assigned to `cmd`, and the first `1` is assigned to `loop_max`. There are no parameter left for the second `1` to be assigned to, so you get the observed error.